# HTML a content top

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have an `a` tag with these content:

```
<a height="0">
    <img style="width:100px; height:100px; display:inline;" src="..." >
    <div style="width:100px; height:100px; display:inline;" src="..." >
        Hello
    </div>
</a>
```

I want: the `div` contents shows from top of `a` but it shows from middle
I set `a`'s `height` to 0 because of my projects not for this issue;
I test css `top` `margin` `padding` `valign` ... but no one make it true

[image]

Comment: Not a solution, just FYI: height and width won't apply to inline elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a lot of ways of implementing it, here is my solution. It's just simply floating elements. Works fine.

```css
img {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<a height="0">
    <img src="..." >
    <div src="..." >
        Hello
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your `div` element a `vertical-align` of `top`:

```css
div {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<a height="0">
    <img style="width:100px; height:100px; display:inline;" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" >
    <div style="width:100px; height:100px; display:inline;" src="..." >
        Hello
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `float:left` for your div

sample http://jsfiddle.net/uLqa2ky5/